# Suspicious Netbios activity

Tags: networking, router, security

My home internet connection has been getting hit with constant Netbios activity from various countries. I went to one of the IPs with Torbrowser and it said something about ShadowServer scanning. Is this normal, or should I be concerned? [image]

Comment: It’s strange that this log says “NetBIOS” when the destination port is telnet (23) or HTTP (80). I wonder if something inside the packets looked like NetBIOS?

Comment: I don't know...

Comment: Where did this log come from? What software?

Comment: My 2Wire Gateway